# python - extract N occurrences of items in a list of a file

Tags: python, list, range

I am trying to extract the 100 first occurrences of each item of a list of file_1.txt to a new file. The list of items (called *target* in the code below)  consists of the first column of file_1.txt

file_1.txt

```
now:::ADV       1.48    be:::V  1.85    5488284
then:::ADV      1.44    be:::V  1.85    3994804
now:::ADV       1.48    have:::V        2.18    1760901
then:::ADV      1.44    have:::V        2.18    1099284
enough:::ADV    1.33    be:::V  1.85    928947
suppose:::V     1.37    be:::V  1.85    874407
ever:::ADV      1.48    be:::V  1.85    859428
```

The code I tried is here:

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as infile, open('file_2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
target = []
i = 1
for line in infile:
    columns = line.split("\t")
    column_1 = columns[0]
    if column_1 not in target:
        target.append(column_1)
    for item in target:
        if line.startswith(item) and i <=100:
            outfile.write(line)
    i += 1
```

This, of course, just prints the 100 first lines of file_1.txt to file_2.txt. Is there a pythonic way of reading just 1 line at a time, appending it to *target* and searching for the 100 first occurrences, print it to file_2.txt and continue with the next unique word in column 1 of file_1.txt?

I really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: do you need the output in order of occurrence of a target or would in order of 100th occurrence be ok?

Comment: @Paul Panzer the order does not matter as long it is within the 100th occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly it won't be possible to achieve them without a bit of buffering. The following approach uses a dictionary for that. It is based on your code:

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as infile, open('file_2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    target = {}

    for line in infile:
        columns = line.split("\t")
        column_1 = columns[0]
        try:
            target[column_1].append(line)
            if len(target[column_1]) == 100:
                for tline in target[column_1]:
                    outfile.write(tline)
                target[column_1] = None # mark word as finished
        except KeyError: # we haven't seen that word before -> start new list
            target[column_1] = [line]
        except AttributeError: # this is raised each time we try appending to None
            pass
```

Comment: great, it exactly produces the output I like to have, thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: your code just misses the 1st occurrence of every word, is that what you asked in your previous comment? I am sorry if I misunderstood it. So file_1.txt is sorted by frequency and I would like to have the first 100 occurrences of a word. Is that an easy fix or does it require a lot of changes?

Comment: really nice, now it is all perfect! Thank you for the edit! great!